# TFS Code Review can not add comments from reviewer

Tags: tfs

in VS code review 
I'm trying to add "overall comments" and add "file comment" from reviewer.
but these option are disabled (marked in grey)
See images below.
What is the reason for this?
Thanks.

[Add overall comments button disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnnDm.png)

[Add file comment button disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwiFS.png)

Answer (score 0):

This code review is supposed to be closed by the requestor. You can check your code review to see whether it is closed as the screenshot shows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not what i asked. Why the user who review the code can not add overall comments or file comment? These options are disabled.

Comment: can anyone answer why these options are not available ??

Comment: If the code review is closed by the requestor, users are not able to add overall comments or file comment, as they are disabled. You need to check whether the code review has been closed.